# How to convert a video without loss in quality?

Tags: video

I have converted a wmv file to a flv file, but it has lost a lot of quality. How to prevent this? I need the file to be smaller in size.

Answer (score 1):

Some references for conversion to FLV using ffmpeg.

- [Using ffmpeg to manipulate audio and video files](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/) is in depth
- [A Layman's Guide to Flash Video Conversion](http://worldtv.com/blog/guides_tutorials/flv_converter.php)
- [What a best line command for FFmpeg convert to FLV Google Translate](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forum/Modules/14154/What-a-best-line-command-for-FFmpeg-convert-to-FLV)
- [How to convert/encode files to FLV using FFMPEG & PHP](http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/) has this example

  - `ffmpeg -i video.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv`

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with the command line, check out [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). Nothing compares to it in terms of video conversion.

Comment: In fact, the file is converted with help of FFMpeg. =)

Comment: It takes quite a few options with `ffmpeg` to get the work done.

Comment: If you used ffmpeg then post the command that you used so we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Moyea Video4Web Converter](http://www.flash-video-mx.com/video4web-converter/):

> Moyea Video4Web Converter, a totally
>   free video to flash video converter,
>   offers excellent solution for the
>   multiple requirements to convert all
>   the fashion video to flash video files
>   so that video share site like YouTube
>   supports, most Mobile phone supports,
>   and Adobe Flash Player supports for
>   Moyea Web Player. 
> Generally, the
>   various inputs of this free video to
>   flash video converter contain WMV,
>   ASF, WMA, AVI, RMVB, RM, RA, MOV, QT,
>   MP4, M4V, 3GP, 3G2, DAT, MPG, MPEG,
>   MP3, VOB, DV and the multi-conversions
>   including converting avi to flv, avi
>   to mp4, avi to mov, 3gp, 3g2;
>   converting wmv to flv, wmv to mp4, wmv
>   to mov, 3gp, 3g2; converting mpg to
>   flv, mpg to mp4, mpeg to mov, 3gp, 3g2
>   and so on.